# Is clipping working properly on rotation?

Tags: svg, raphael

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H5GhH/

The black rectangle is drawn, just to show where the clip path is appearing. The red rectangles are our object that needs to be clipped.

After rotating the object(red rectangle) by 20Deg, the bottom right corner of the red rectangle
            has to be clipped against the black bordered rectangle, also since the red rectangle is
            heigh enoguh, the bottom left corner should not be seen.(imagine rotating the right side red rectangle 20Deg clockwise and compare the results with the left red rectangle.)

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new g tag(group) and moving all the elements to that group and then applying clip-path to g tag works. ClipPath doesn't recognize transform of attribute of element if applied to individual elems. So it should be wrapped in g for this.